# DOTween transform.DOMove function changes scale of object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dotween

Hi I am using DOTween for some smooth transformation.

```
Collider _leftForeArmBounds = leftForeArm.GetComponent<Collider>();
    for (int i = 0; i < leftForeArmCubes.Count; i++)
        leftForeArmCubes[i].transform.DOMove(ExtensionMethods.RandomPointInBounds(_leftForeArmBounds), cubeMoveDuration);
```

I have this code and the cubes in the list are child of a game object. The problem starts here. While cubes are moving their scale also smoothly increasing to the parent's.

I have used this very same code before in one of my previous game but it didn't happen then. This is not the first time I am using DOTween but I really don't understand what is going on is this some kind of bug?

Thank you

Comment: I suspect that parents aren't uniformly scaled and cause skewing. Try moving the problematic cubes manually in the same direction as DOTween and you'll see the same results.

Comment: I've tried moving them manually before but scale didn't change

Comment: What are the Transform values of the object's parents?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try DOLocalMove method.

Comment: Nope I am calculating world position so I need global movement. I tried anyways but objects gone to hell